# How to compare a program's version in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, test, version, numeric-data

Suppose I want to compare `gcc` version to see whether the system has the minimum version installed or not.

To check the `gcc` version, I executed the following

```
gcc --version | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f4
```

The output was

```
4.8.5
```

So, I wrote a simple `if` statement to check this version against some other value

```
if [ "$(gcc --version | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f4)" -lt 5.0.0 ]; then
    echo "Less than 5.0.0"
else
    echo "Greater than 5.0.0"
fi
```

But it throws an error:

```
[: integer expression expected: 4.8.5
```

I understood my mistake that I was using strings to compare and the `-lt` requires integer. So, is there any other way to compare the versions?

Comment: There's also a [Stack Overflow question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format) with a bunch of different suggestions for comparing version strings.

Comment: Much simpler than using pipes: `gcc -dumpversion`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't know if it is beautiful, but it is working for every version format I know.

```
#!/bin/bash
currentver="$(gcc -dumpversion)"
requiredver="5.0.0"
 if [ "$(printf '%s\n' "$requiredver" "$currentver" | sort -V | head -n1)" = "$requiredver" ]; then 
        echo "Greater than or equal to ${requiredver}"
 else
        echo "Less than ${requiredver}"
 fi
```

(**Note:** better version by the user 'wildcard': https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135943/wildcard , removed additional condition)

Comment: or you could use `sort`'s own checking facilities `if printf '%s\n%s\n' "$(gcc --version | head -n1 | awk '{print $NF}')" 5.0.0 | sort -cV; then echo 'less'; else echo 'more'; fi` - admittedly less readable

Comment: At first I thought this was awful, and then I realized the beauty of shell scripting is precisely in abusing tools like this.  +1

Comment: This breaks if there are '%' signs in the print statement. Better replace `printf "$requiredver\n$currentver"` with `printf '%s\n' "$requiredver" "$currentver"`.

Comment: `-V` is a GNU extension of `sort(1)` thus this solution is non-portable.

Comment: `sort -n` works pretty much the same way in case of numeral versions.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini, see what you think of my edit.

Comment: I am reading it. Looks great! It is better now, do you want to make it the official version and remove the other form?

Comment: @Rockallite: No, not quite the same. ```sort -n``` will sort 4.10 as lower than 4.9.

Answer (score 15):

Shorter version, assuming GNU `sort`:

```
version_greater_equal()
{
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$2" "$1" | sort --check=quiet --version-sort
}

version_greater_equal "${gcc_version}" 8.2 || die "need 8.2 or above"
```

Note that it would report `gcc_version=008.002` as not being satisfactory even though it sorts the same as `8.2`. That can be alleviated by adding the `-s` / `--stable` option to `sort`.

Comment: (1) This is a minor variation of already-given answers.  You could add value by adding an explanation, which has not yet been posted.  (2) ``printf '%s\n'`` is good enough; `printf` will repeat the format string as needed.

Comment: I normally prefer editing existing answers but deleting half of them is tricky: others may see value where I don't. Same for verbose explanations. Less is more.

Comment: I know that `printf` repeats the format string but I the (lack of!) syntax for this is IMHO obscure; so I use this only when required = when the number of arguments is large or variable.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Comment: What is `die` ?

Comment: `die` is whatever error handling function you want. It's a common name for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here I give a solution for comparing Unix Kernel versions.  And it should work for others such as gcc. I only care for the first 2 version number but you can add another layer of logic.  It is one liner and I wrote it in multiple line for understanding.

```
check_linux_version() {
    version_good=$(uname -r | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="."}; 
    { if ($1 < 4) { print "N"; } 
      else if ($1 == 4) { 
          if ($2 < 4) { print "N"; } 
          else { print "Y"; } 
      } 
      else { print "Y"; }
    }')

    #if [ "$current" \< "$expected" ]; then
    if [ "$version_good" = "N" ]; then
        current=$(uname -r)
        echo current linux version too low
        echo current Linux: $current
        echo required 4.4 minimum
        return 1
    fi
}
```

You can modify this and use it for gcc version checking.

Answer (score 2):

We used to do a lot of version checking in a GNU makefile. We shelled out through the makefile facilities. We had to detect old Binutils and buggy compilers and workaround them on the fly.

The pattern we used was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CC=$(command -v gcc)
GREP=$(command -v grep)

# Fixup CC and GREP as needed. It may be needed on AIX, BSDs, and Solaris
if [[ -f "/usr/gnu/bin/grep" ]]; then
    GREP="/usr/gnu/bin/grep"
elif [[ -f "/usr/linux/bin/grep" ]]; then
    GREP="/usr/linux/bin/grep"
elif [[ -f "/usr/xpg4/bin/grep" ]]; then
    GREP="/usr/xpg4/bin/grep"
fi

# Check compiler for GCC 4.8 or later
GCC48_OR_LATER=$("$CXX" -v 2>&1 | "$GREP" -i -c -E "gcc version (4\.[8-9]|[5-9]\.)")
if [[ "$GCC48_OR_LATER" -ne 0 ]];
then
   ...
fi

# Check assembler for GAS 2.19 or later
GAS219_OR_LATER=$("$CXX" -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | "$GREP" -c -E "GNU assembler version (2\.19|2\.[2-9]|[3-9])")
if [[ "$GAS219_OR_LATER" -ne 0 ]];
then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: Nice! This works and is super easy to extend, and very portable!

Comment: "`"$GREP" -i -c -E "gcc version (4\.[8-9]|[5-9]\.)")`" This fails for gcc >=10 (the current version is 11.1.0).  I think it might be more future-proof to check if it's lesser than 4.8 instead.  But as a simple fix, the following should probably work for any future major versions (e.g.: 999): `"$GREP" -i -c -E "gcc version (4\.[8-9]|[5-9]\.|[1-9][0-9]*\.)")`.  The same issue might affect the GAS check at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
function version_compare () {
  function sub_ver () {
    local len=${#1}
    temp=${1%%"."*} && indexOf=`echo ${1%%"."*} | echo ${#temp}`
    echo -e "${1:0:indexOf}"
  }
  function cut_dot () {
    local offset=${#1}
    local length=${#2}
    echo -e "${2:((++offset)):length}"
  }
  if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "=" && exit 0
  fi
  local v1=`echo -e "${1}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]'`
  local v2=`echo -e "${2}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]'`
  local v1_sub=`sub_ver $v1`
  local v2_sub=`sub_ver $v2`
  if (( v1_sub > v2_sub )); then
    echo ">"
  elif (( v1_sub < v2_sub )); then
    echo "<"
  else
    version_compare `cut_dot $v1_sub $v1` `cut_dot $v2_sub $v2`
  fi
}

### Usage:

version_compare "1.2.3" "1.2.4"
# Output: <
```

Credit goes to [@Shellman](https://github.com/yousefvand/shellman)

Answer (score 1):

With [lastversion](https://github.com/dvershinin/lastversion) CLI utility you can compare any arbitrary versions, e.g.:

```bsh
#> lastversion 1.0.0 -gt 0.9.9
#> 1.0.0
```

Exit code 0 when "greater" condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you can use it's `n`umeric `o`rdering (`O`rdering in reverse) parameter expansion flags:

```
at_least() [[ $1 = ${${(On)@}[1]} ]]
```

And then:

```
if at_least $version 1.12; then
   ...
fi
```

Note that `1.12-pre1` or `1.12-alpha3` would be considered greater than 1.12. 1.012 sorts the same as 1.12 but since one has to come before the other and  we do an equality comparison we'll end up considering it not `at_least 1.12`.

zsh also comes with an `autoload`able [`is-at-least` function](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/zsh-5.9/tree/Functions/Misc/is-at-least) aimed for that (intended to compare zsh version numbers but can be used with any version provided they use similar versioning scheme as zsh's):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
autoload is-at-least
if
  version=$(gcc -dumpfullversion 2> /dev/null) &&
    [[ -n $version ]] &&
    is-at-least 7.2 $version
then
  ...
fi
```

(we need to check that `$version` is `n`on-empty as [otherwise `is-at-least` would compare zsh's own version](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00536.html)).

Note that `-dumpfullversion` was added in gcc 7.1.0. `-dumpversion`  has been available for decades but note that it may only give the major version number.

From `info gcc dumpversion` in the manual from gcc-12.2.0:

> '-dumpversion'
> Print the compiler version (for example, '3.0', '6.3.0' or
> '7')--and don't do anything else.  This is the compiler version
> used in filesystem paths and specs.  Depending on how the compiler
> has been configured it can be just a single number (major version),
> two numbers separated by a dot (major and minor version) or three
> numbers separated by dots (major, minor and patchlevel version).
>
> '-dumpfullversion'
> Print the full compiler version--and don't do anything else.  The
> output is always three numbers separated by dots, major, minor and
> patchlevel version.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -dumpversion
12
$ gcc -dumpfullversion
12.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of the work by [Kemin Zhou](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/164229/kemin-zhou) [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418966/469806) which offers a solution for checking if a kernel version *major_version.minor_version* is newer than some arbitrary linux kernel of *major_version.minor_version*, ignoring the rest of the kernel version string.

```
#!/bin/bash
check_linux_version() {
    maj_ver=$1
    min_ver=$2
    version_good=$(uname -r | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="."};
    { if ($1 < '"${maj_ver}"') { print "N"; }
      else if ($1 == '"${maj_ver}"') {
          if ($2 < '"${min_ver}"') { print "N"; }
          else { print "Y"; }
      }
      else { print "Y"; }
    }')

    if [ "$version_good" = "N" ]; then
        return 1
    fi
}
if check_linux_version 4 16; then echo Y ; else echo N; fi
if check_linux_version 5 10; then echo Y ; else echo N; fi
if check_linux_version 6 2; then echo Y ; else echo N; fi
```

I'm using this code [here](https://github.com/chromebrew/chromebrew/blob/665b38f135626eec9cb3fd6f14fe66fc240bf35d/packages/sommelier.rb#L100) in the [Chromebrew](https://github.com/chromebrew/chromebrew) project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that doesn't depend on bash

```
compare_versions()
{
  var1=$1;
  var2=$2;
  for i in 1 2 3
  do
    part1=$(echo $var1 | cut -d "." -f $i)
    part2=$(echo $var2 | cut -d "." -f $i)
    if [ $part1 -lt $part2 ]
    then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}
```

this can then be run like

```
if compare_versions `gcc --version` "5.0.0"
then
  echo "Less than 5.0.0"
else
  echo "Greater than or equal to 5.0.0"
fi
```

Comment: What does "_edit want take split on . off afterwards and turn back on globbing_" mean? If you want to edit your answer please just do so. There is a full edit history so it's easy for people to see what you changed

Answer (score 0):

## If the program is Python

The question is not `gcc` specific though many answers are.<sup>*</sup> Even the excellent general answers using `cut -d" "` will fail for older Python because prior to v3.4, `python --version` wrote to *stderr* instead of stdout. (!!)

Here is a short `bash` command to check that your *Python* is at least v3.8 (or whatever you use), that uses Python to avoid both stderr issues and the gyrations involved with *sh string comparison.

```bash
python -c "import sys; sys.version_info < (3,8) and sys.exit(1)" \
    && echo "At least v3.8!" || echo "Old version. Do not use."
```

Note that the version is a Python tuple like (3, 8, 18, "final", 0) so if you needed at least v3.8.13, you would use (3, 8, 13).

My use case: stop `pip` if Python is too old, before I accidentally install hundreds of packages for the wrong environment.

```bash
$ python -V \
>   && python -c "import sys; sys.version_info < (3,8) and sys.exit(1)" \
>   && echo "Python version OK" \
>   && echo "UPDATING PIP..." \
>   && python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
>   && echo "UPDATING MYPACKAGE..." \
>   && python -m pip install .[dev] \
>   || echo "Old Python or other error."

Python 2.7.18
Old Python or other error.
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The question is: "How to compare **a program's** version in a shell script?"  It gives `gcc` as an example but is not limited to `gcc`.