# Bash - Integer expression expected

Tags: shell-script, string, test, numeric-data

I am making the check for update script for my theme

I have 2 text files. First one is called "current.txt" and contains the current version. There is `4.1.1` string in that text file.

Second one is called "latest.txt" and contains the latest version. There is `4.2` string in this text file.

So here is the code

```
echo "Checking update";
x=$(cat ./current.txt)
y=$(cat ./latest.txt)
if [ "$x" -eq "$y" ]
then
       echo There is version $y update
else
       echo Version $x is the latest version
fi
```

What it mean is if current.txt is NOT the same with latest.txt then it will say "there is version 4.2 update". If not, it will say "version 4.1.1 is the latest version"

But when I try to run it. I get this error

```
Checking update
./test.sh: line 4: [: 4.1.1: integer expression expected
Version 4.1.1 is the latest version
```

So what am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285928/117549

Comment: A slight optimization: use `x=$(< ./current.txt)` -- that's builtin, so you don't need to call out to cat (ref [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution))

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) command, also named `[`, has separate operators for string comparisons and integer comparisons:

> INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
>
> INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2

vs

> STRING1 = STRING2
>
> the strings are equal

and

> STRING1 != STRING2
>
> the strings are not equal

Since your data is not strictly an integer, your test needs to use the string comparison operator. The last realization in the comments was that the "-eq" logic did not match the sense of the if/else `echo` statements, so the new snippet should be:

```
...
if [ "$x" != "$y" ]
then
       echo There is version $y update
else
       echo Version $x is the latest version
fi
```

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72042/117549

Comment: It should be noted when you're using the `-a/o` ("and" / "or") operators, you don't need anything to separate the expressions. Just do: `if [ $int1 -le $int2 -o $int3 -gt $int4 ]`.

Answer (score 5):

BTW, if you have two version strings (e.g. in `$x` and `$y`) you can use `printf` and GNU `sort` to find which is newer.

```
$ x=4.1.1
$ y=4.2.2
$ printf "%s\n" "$x" "$y" | sort -V -r
4.2.2
4.1.1

$ if [ $(printf "%s\n" "$x" "$y" | sort -V -r | head -1) = "$x" ] ; then
  if [ "$x" = "$y" ] ; then
    echo "$x is equal to $y"
  else
    echo "$x is newer than $y"
  fi
else
  echo "$x is older than $y"
fi
4.1.1 is older than 4.2.2
```