# How to check if a **program** version is equal to or smaller than x

Tags: bash, shell-script, version

I'm writing a shell script that has to know if a certain program version is less or equal to version x.xx.xx

here is an example script to try and explain what I want to do:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

APPVER="`some command to output version | grep x.xx*`"

if [[ "$APPVER" is smaller or equal to "x.xx*" ]]; then
    do something
else
    do something else
fi
```

is there a way to do that? I found ways to compare numbers, but they won't work with version numbers.
I need a solution that uses no or as little as possible programs.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome, when you say "app", what exactly do you mean? Packages?

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285924/315749

Comment: some program app, it doesn't really matter. for the code I have a app/program output a version for example 1.5.30 and I need to check if its less or equal to 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU sort, use its [version comparison mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-version-number-sort).

```
if { echo "$APPVER"; echo "x.y.z"; } | sort --version-sort --check; then
  echo "App version is x.y.x or less"
fi
```

Comment: when testing your code like this:
```bash
APPVER="1.13"

if { echo "$APPVER"; echo "1.12.9"; } | sort --version-sort --check; then
  echo "App version is 1.12.9 or less"
fi
```
I get this error: `sort: -:2: disorder: 1.12.9`
but it works when using it like this:
```bash
APPVER="1.12.2"

if { echo "$APPVER"; echo "1.12.9"; } | sort --version-sort --check; then
  echo "App version is 1.12.9 or less"
fi
```

do you know why?

Comment: 1.13 isn't 1.12.9 or less, but 1.12.2 is, so what's the problem?

Comment: I think I found what was wrong, there is no `else` so I got a error, your script worked perfectly fine, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can do it with `printf -v`:

```
vercomp(){
   local a b IFS=. -; set -f
   printf -v a %08d $1; printf -v b %08d $3
   test $a "$2" $b
}

if vercomp 2.50.1 \< 2.6; then
   echo older
else
   echo newer
fi
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly your code is doing please?

Comment: It implements a bash function which compares two version strings, without using external commands like `sort` or spawning subprocesses with `$(...)`. It's limited to plain version strings like `5.8.12` or `12.3.08.1`; it will not work with `2.5.3-alpha1` or version/patchlevel combos. It's also bash-only, it doesnt't work with a standard shell.

Comment: this answer helped me a lot, but I'm marking the other one as the answer because its simpler.
in real world usage this answer is more useful though.